# Save a webform as draft?

Tags: webforms, nodes

I want to save a webform as draft for logged in user. I read somewhere that this a default feature but not able to find out. I could not find this option "Allow users to save a draft" in the form settings(Using Drupal7 and webform 3.13). Please suggest.

Comment: Go through this [Use AJAX to auto save a draft](https://www.drupal.org/node/1319926)

Comment: @Mołot There is no option for saving as draft in configuration settings of webform.Yes I am using multistep form.

Comment: The option should be at /node/XX/webform/configure in the last fieldset (advanced settings). It's named >Show "Save draft" button<.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a "Save as Draft" button in webforms. Check the permissions with "allow users to save draft" in the permission page.

There has been an issue reported [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/743722) with the same problem as yours.

Comment: I am using Drupal7 and not able to find this "Save as Draft" option and  "allow users to save draft" permission as well.